# nextjs route middleware for authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to figure out an appropriate way of doing authentication, which I know is a touchy subject on the [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/153).

My authentication is simple. I store a JWT token in the session. I send it to a different server for approval. If I get back true, we keep going, if I get back false, it clears the session and puts sends them to the main page.

In my `server.js` file I have the following (note- I am using the example from [nextjs learn](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-dynamic-pages) and just adding `isAuthenticated`):

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  //checks go here

  //if (req.user.authenticated)
   // return next();

  // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
  res.redirect('/');
}

server.get('/p/:id', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = '/post'
  const queryParams = { id: req.params.id }
  app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
})
```

This works as designed. If I refresh the page `/p/123`, it will redirect to the `/`. However, if I go there via a `next/link` href, it doesn't. Which I believe is because it's not using express at this point but next's custom routing.

Is there a way I can bake in a check for every single `next/link` that doesn't go through express so that I can make sure the user is logged in?

Answer (score 13):

***Edit:** Updated answer for Next 12.2+*

> Note: The below contents is copied from the official blog post since SO generally discourages links that can become stale/dead over time
> https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2#middleware-stable

Middleware is now stable in 12.2 and has an improved API based on feedback from users.

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

// If the incoming request has the "beta" cookie
// then we'll rewrite the request to /beta
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const isInBeta = JSON.parse(req.cookies.get('beta') || 'false');
  req.nextUrl.pathname = isInBeta ? '/beta' : '/';
  return NextResponse.rewrite(req.nextUrl);
}

// Supports both a single value or an array of matches
export const config = {
  matcher: '/',
};
```

### Migration guide

> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide
> Breaking changes

- No Nested Middleware
- No Response Body
- Cookies API Revamped
- New User-Agent Helper
- No More Page Match Data
- Executing Middleware on Internal Next.js Requests

#### How to upgrade

You should declare **one single Middleware file** in your application, which should be located next to the `pages` directory and named **without** an `_` prefix. Your Middleware file can still have either a `.ts` or `.js` extension.

Middleware will be invoked for **every route in the app**, and a custom matcher can be used to define matching filters. The following is an example for a Middleware that triggers for `/about/*` and `/dashboard/:path*`, the custom matcher is defined in an exported config object:

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('/about-2', request.url))
}

// Supports both a single string value or an array of matchers
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/about/:path*', '/dashboard/:path*'],
}
```

---

***Edit:** Outdated answer for next > 12 and < 12.2*

With the release of Next.js 12, there's now beta support for middleware using Vercel Edge Functions.

> *https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#introducing-middleware*
>
> Middleware uses a strict runtime that supports standard Web APIs like fetch. > This works out of the box using next start, as well as on Edge platforms like Vercel, which use Edge Functions.
>
> To use Middleware in Next.js, you can create a file pages/_middleware.js. In this example, we use the standard Web API Response (MDN):

```js
// pages/_middleware.js

export function middleware(req, ev) {
  return new Response('Hello, world!')
}
```

### JWT Authentication example

- https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/jwt-authentication

in `next.config.js`:

```js
const withTM = require('@vercel/edge-functions-ui/transpile')()

module.exports = withTM()
```

in `pages/_middleware.js`:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { setUserCookie } from '@lib/auth'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // Add the user token to the response
  return setUserCookie(req, NextResponse.next())
}
```

in `pages/api/_middleware.js`:

```js
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { verifyAuth } from '@lib/auth'
import { jsonResponse } from '@lib/utils'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.nextUrl

  if (url.searchParams.has('edge')) {
    const resOrPayload = await verifyAuth(req)

    return resOrPayload instanceof Response
      ? resOrPayload
      : jsonResponse(200, { nanoid: nanoid(), jwtID: resOrPayload.jti })
  }
}
```

in `pages/api/index.js`:

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { verify, JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import { USER_TOKEN, JWT_SECRET_KEY } from '@lib/constants'

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    return res.status(405).json({
      error: { message: 'Method not allowed' },
    })
  }
  try {
    const token = req.cookies[USER_TOKEN]
    const payload = verify(token, JWT_SECRET_KEY) as JwtPayload
    res.status(200).json({ nanoid: nanoid(), jwtID: payload.jti })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: { message: 'Your token has expired.' } })
  }
}
```

Comment: Nested middlewares are no longer supported, so this won't work on latter versions.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated to include latest guidance from the 12.2 announcement blob post and official migration guide

Comment: read the cookie in the middleware  like what you said , does not work . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75750941/nextjs-middleware-can-not-read-the-cookie-after-set-it-needs-to-reload-the-page

Answer (score 3):

There is no `middleware` for no API routes in `NextJS`, but there are HOCs, which you can use to connect to db - select the user, etc:
https://hoangvvo.com/blog/nextjs-middleware