# NextJS API – Middleware using Dynamic Routes [...]

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js, middleware

I've found severals way of doing middleware with Nextjs eg:

- [nextjs route middleware for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426252/nextjs-route-middleware-for-authentication) (extending using _app.js)
- https://github.com/senchalabs/connect (writting middleware in express server layer)

---

But may I know is there a possible way to do middleware using [Dynamic API Routes methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes)?

eg:

1. add a file on `pages/api/auth/[...middleware].js`
2. all the request from `pages/api/auth/*` will handled by `[...middleware].js`

Recently I came across with a cool nextjs auth package: (https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example)

[image]

I've studied the source and try with below codes on `pages/api/[...middleware].js`

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    const done = resolve;

    console.log('Auth Middleware....')
    return done();
  })
}
```

but when i try to fetch the url:

**http://localhost:3000/api/auth/user**

The terminal/console doesn't output the console of 'Auth Middleware....'