# NextJs middleware Can not read the cookie after set, it needs to reload the page

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, middleware, next.js13

After setting the **cookie**, I can not read it in the middleware , I have to **reload the page** then I can read the **cookie**.

Why did this happen?

I set cookie like the following:

```
import { getCookies, setCookie, deleteCookie, hasCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function LoginPage() {

    const router = useRouter()

    const login = () => {
        if (hasCookie('user')) {
            router.push('/');
            return;
        }

        setCookie('user', 'DHamidi-RandomValue')
        router.push('/');
    }

    return <div className="layout">
        <h2>Login</h2>

        <button onClick={login}>
            Add User Info To Cookie.
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

I want to read the cookie in the middleware:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    if (request.cookies.has('user')) return NextResponse.next()
    
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.nextUrl.clone()))
}

export const config = {
    matcher: '/admin/:path*',
}
```

NOTE:

It works in development mode perfectly (`npm run dev`).but the problem happens in production mode(`npm run build => npm run start`).

If you want to see the problem in action, **[Please clone this simple project](https://github.com/darushHamidi/next-middleware)**

Answer (score 1):

when you set the cookie; include path=/ and you will be able to access the cookie without refreshing the page. Please let me know if it works.

res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${60 * 60}; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure`);

Comment: @johnnn- Thank you so much for your answer I have to say, when I set the path to / it does not work.
for more information, you can close the above repository and try it to find out what I'm saying exactly. https://github.com/darushHamidi/next-middleware

Comment: You are saying that it doesn't work in production mode and the problem might be about an environment value you are using in development mode. When you deploy the project, you need to define these variable in the deployment platform (vercel for instance).I experienced a similar problem in production mode. I found out that I was neglecting to include .env variables in production platform. So please keep in mind that you might need to update urls or environment variables for the production mode. For example, if in your code, you have a url like "localhost....", it won't work in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're encountering an issue where your Next.js middleware isn't being triggered consistently in production mode, unlike in development mode. This is likely due to Next.js caching the responses to prevent unnecessary re-executions and improve performance.

To ensure your middleware triggers every time on production, you need to set the x-middleware-cache header to no-cache in the redirect response:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.cookies.has('user')) {
    return NextResponse.next(); 
  }

  const redirectResponse = NextResponse.redirect('URL_HERE');
  redirectResponse.headers.set('x-middleware-cache', 'no-cache'); // ! FIX: Disable caching
  return redirectResponse;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/admin/:path*'
};
```

With this change, Next.js won't cache the redirect response in production, causing your middleware to run on every request, similar to what you're experiencing in development mode.

For further understanding, you can refer to this GitHub discussion: https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/8173